# Xaml + Directx Fullscene Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: windows, xaml, directx, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I use visual studio 2015, and created a Visual C++ Universal: DirectX11 and XAML App (Universal Windows) Project.
I run on Device or emulator and get the result as shown in the photo below

[image: Result]

I want my game displayed fullscreen.

Answer (score 2):

See [ApplicationView.TryEnterFullScreenMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryenterfullscreenmode.aspx)

Comment: thanks, It runs perfectly on phone. However, the pc, when I move the mouse pointer over the top edge, the title appears. I want my game occupy the full screen.